# Send SMS through intent to multiple phone numbers

Tags: android, sms

When i sending the sms through Intent an exception comes **android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=vnd.android-dir/mms-sms (has extras) }**

See my code below:-

```
try {

                 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("smsto:5551212;5551212"));
                 sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", sendSMSStringOnCustomCheckIn()); 
                 sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                 startActivity(sendIntent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want to send the SMS to 2 phone nembers and both the phone numbers should be display in the recipient box of default SMS box.How can i do that?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/

Comment: Didn't help this link because it says only to add message  :(

Comment: why not use sms manager

Comment: Because the user can write the text according to his need.That's why i have to open  the SMS box default.Why you downvote it??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the solution of my Question. In **SAMSUNG** devices i have to separate the phone numbers with **','** while other devices are accept the **';'**.So unfortunately have to do this ugly vendor specific decision within your source code.

```
 String separator = "; ";


 if(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("Samsung")){
    separator = ", ";
  }
```

Now my below code is working properly for SAMSUNG devices.

```
try {

                 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 sendIntent.putExtra("address", "9971227563,9990900909");
                 sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", sendSMSStringOnCustomCheckIn());
                 sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                 startActivity(sendIntent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Xiaomi, Samsung, Nexus 5 are working with `;` separator.