# Send SMS to multiple recipients via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am trying to send `SMS` to multiple recipients via`INTENT`. I tried the following to do it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", etmessage.getText().toString());
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + returnedItems));
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
mcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Where `returnedItems` is of Contact Numbers

But the problem is that my recipients numbers are not setting on `TO` section on `SMS INTENT` where `TEXT` is displayed on `TEXT` section.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that the numbers are seperated by **`;`** .

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("smsto:1234456;234567"));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", etmessage.getText().toString());
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

always works for me!

Comment: How did you find that out?

Answer (score 5):

Did you tried below ?

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("smsto:999999;888888"));
```

I also found out ";" is not working in Samsung device. You have to add "," instead of ";" for samsungs devices.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("smsto:999999,888888"));
```

Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18975676/624069)

Comment: I do wonder why OP has not accepted nor '+1'ed this anwser... Good answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse("smsto:" + pointsList));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi Friends & Families, My Location is feeling unsafe in this location");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

pointsList is something like `ArrayList`, for example `[8777675673,8566463454,7776666664]`.
It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by the following way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String numbers = "1234567890;9876543210;453678920"
intent.putExtra("address", numbers);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getString(R.string.share_image)));
```

The numbers are separated by semi-colon (`;`). I read in some mobile phones the numbers need to separated by comma (`,`).

Hope this will help.